# using jsts in angular

Tags: angular, openlayers

When I am trying to use jsts library in angular application as below

```
import * as jsts from 'jsts'; // does not work
import * as jsts from 'jsts/dist/jsts'; // does not work
import * as jsts from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/OL3Parser"; // does not work
```

for adding jsts lib I have used `npm install jsts`  have also added types of jsts as `npm i --save-dev @types/jsts` .But still It is saying `cannot find module 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/OL3Parser";' or its corresponding type declarations`.